# Game Center integration with Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center, sprite-kit

How can I use Game Center or the GameKit Framework with a Sprite Kit Xcode template?
In Sprite kit, it uses Scenes; but normally to view the leaderboards for example you need to "presentModalViewController" but that is not possible in SKView.

And how can I authenticate the player and all that other fun stuff in iOS 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use modalViews - i am using it for my settings, works great. This will get you started, UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController

Comment: if you cannot get it to work, post another question and ill write up answer for you.

Comment: I still can't get the GKGameCentreViewController to open up inside a SKView. Could you help? this is the error i get... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is <GKGameCenterViewController

Comment: create a new question, asking for how to present a modal view in sprite kit - ill get to it as asap

Comment: ok i crated a new question here is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504461/how-to-present-a-modal-view-in-sprite-kit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can authenticate like this

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                static_setEnable( true );

                NSLog(@" Authenticate local player complete");

            }
            else
            {
                static_setEnable( false );
                NSLog(@"Authenticate local player Error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a very good answer because SpriteKit is only available on iOS 7 but `authenticateWithCompletionHandler:` is deprecated since iOS 6.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "presentModalViewController" by using this code to access the root view controller

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Now you can access your ModelViewController anywhere include in SKScenes. I did it in my newest game and it worked well

Besides, I suggest you use the separate object to control game center like leaderboard and achievement so you can reuse it in your next game.

Comment: its not working, so i tried this... GKGameCenterViewController *vc = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        [vc presentViewController:vc animated: YES completion:nil]; and stil not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated authenticate local player, but Ravindra's code also works.

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil)
        {
            //showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: is an example method name. Create your own method that displays an authentication view when appropriate for your app.
            //[self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController];
        }
        else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            //authenticatedPlayer: is an example method name. Create your own method that is called after the loacal player is authenticated.
            //[self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
        }
        else
        {
            //[self disableGameCenter];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0

```
 func authenticateLocalPlayer() {

        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {  (viewController, error )  -> Void in

            if (viewController != nil) {

                let vc:UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
                vc.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion:nil)

            } else {


                print ("Authentication is \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated) ")
                GlobalData.loggedIntoGC = true



                // do something based on the player being logged in.
```

GlobalData Swift File:

```
static var loggedIntoGC:Bool = false
```

Call Method in your scene where Game Center is being enabled: 
ie HUD or GameScene in the

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)` 
    authenticateLocalPlayer()
```