# How to present a modal view in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, presentmodalviewcontroller, sprite-kit

How can I use Game Center or the GameKit Framework with a Sprite Kit Xcode template? In Sprite kit, it uses Scenes; but normally to view the leaderboards for example you need to "presentModalViewController" but that is not possible in SKView.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Smick pointed me in the right direction for a similar problem I was having.  I needed to send a message to the main ViewController from my SKScene.  This did it for me:

In your SKScene, import the ViewController

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
```

Then send it a message:

```
[(MyViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController  myMethod];
```

You could try creating a method in the ViewController that opens the GameKit view for you, that is triggered from the SKScene.
Thanks Smick!

Answer (score 1):

presentModalViewController must be called on the view controller your SKView sits on.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how i can connect that to a SKLabelNode that I use as a button

Comment: If you created your game using the sprite kit template it would have created a view controller for you. SKLabelNode inherits off UIResponder so addTarget:action:forControlEvents: should work.

Comment: I tried this in my SKView but its not working. help! - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    //if button touched...
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"achievements"]) {
        //do whatever...
        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [bttn addTarget:vc action:@selector(gamecenter) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up the settings view in the storyboard, ie

[image]

Then if you add a sprite and use for a button i.e. _settingsBtn it will perform the segue

```
    - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([_settingsBtn containsPoint:location]) {
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settingsPushSegue" sender:self];
        }
    }
```

Then you can use a unwind segue to remove it, just a a UIButton.

Have this in your view controller class..

```
- (IBAction)unwindToHideSettingsModal:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    //NSLog(@"UNWILD");
}
```

So now on the storyboard, control drag from your button you added to the green exit segue, and select the above unwind segue.

[image]

Now you will have it show and hide as expected. You can design your settings UI ect in the storyboard.

That should get you started.

Comment: its not working. I'm trying to show the GKGameCenterViewConroller not a view on the storyboard.

Comment: post your app and ill look if you like

Comment: This presents a modal view as question asked, I havent used game centre with ios7 so might be best if you get this book http://www.raywenderlich.com/53279/ios-games-by-tutorials-version-1-0-now-available it covers all game centre info