# Sprite Kit Game Center Leaderboards

Tags: sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

so I've been reading articles and the Apple developer library for a while but I'm not able to solve this.

I want to have a Game Center Leaderboard for my app, that's accessible through my game menu. However, since I'm using Sprite Kit for creating my game this causing me some problems.

I registered my app in iTunes Connect, enabled Game Center and the Identity information within Xcode matches the ones in iTunes Connect.

I created a button, that should open the Game Center Leaderboard. When it's tapped this is called:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController    alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {
            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }

    }
```

Now I get the message, that  Game Center is unavailable because no player is signed in.

To fix that I tried using the authentication method from apple:

`- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil)
        {
            //showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: is an example method name.
            [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController];
        }
        else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            //authenticatedPlayer: is an example method name. 
            [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
        }
        else
        {
            [self disableGameCenter];
        }
    }];
}`

I'm now having trouble defining these methods being called in the authentication method.

My explicit question: How do I authenticate a local player?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Game Center integration with Sprite Kit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473739/game-center-integration-with-sprite-kit)

Comment: This article didn't came to any solution. There haven't been any article that could tell me how to authenticate a local player.